# Filtering array of objects with arrays based on nested value

Tags: javascript, filtering

I am trying to filter an array, based on some nested object. I prepared some [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZnN2/249/)

Input array looks like this:

```
let arrayOfElements = 
    [
        {
           "name": "a",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {"surname": 1},
             {"surname": 2}
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "b",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {"surname": 3},
             {"surname": 1}
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "c",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {"surname": 2},
             {"surname": 5}
           ]
        }
    ];
```

I want the output for this case, to look like this:

```
let filteredArray = 
    [
        {
          "name": "a",
          "subElements": 
          [
            {"surname": 1}
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "b",
          "subElements": 
          [
            {"surname": 1}
          ]
        }
];
```

I am using this formula to do that:

```
let filteredArray = arrayOfElements.filter((element) => element.subElements.some((subElement) => subElement.surname === 1));
```

Output is almost good, but it returns objects with all objects with surnames (better check that fiddle :D), instead of cutting them away. How can i improve the filtering ?

Comment: Are you trying to group based on surname? I mean same thing should group `a` and `c` since they have surname `2`. Right?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This way you can go as deep as you want in an array and filter elements at any level,

```
arrayOfElements.map((element) => {
  return {...element, subElements: element.subElements.filter((subElement) => subElement.surname === 1)}
})
```

Spread operator will expand `element` and then filtered `subElements` will override the `subElements` in element.

Comment: this should be the answer because the accepted answer is not producing the expected output

Comment: Yes, this answer is better. When the accepted answer was written, the Object spread operator did not exist.

Comment: This is modifying original array

Comment: @Aadam can you share your array ? Array.map doesn't modify the original array but returns a new array with modified values.

Comment: This solution has the problem that is will return the same number of elements as the original. They will have the subElements array empty, so a correction would be to add a filter to the result map by checking the length of subElements.

Comment: @Nitesh Ranjan  Its filtering only 2 levels.. After that its not filtering. Any solutions for that?

Comment: This is not removing the third object completely

Comment: Filter the result array to delete the third empty element

let filteredArray = arrayOfElements.map((element) => {
  return {...element, subElements: element.subElements.filter((subElement) => subElement.surname === 1)}
}).filter(elem => elem.subElements.length > 0);

Comment: Here, how to filter for name = a and also surname = 1?

Answer (score 29):

After you call `filter`, you need to pipe the results to `map`, like this:

```
let filteredArray = arrayOfElements
  .filter((element) => 
    element.subElements.some((subElement) => subElement.surname === 1))
  .map(element => {
    let newElt = Object.assign({}, element); // copies element
    return newElt.subElements.filter(subElement => subElement.surname === '1');
  });
```

I am assuming here that you don't want to manipulate the original array. So, I am using Object.assign.

Comment: isn't this returning just the array of subElements instead of the full object with the filtered subarray?

Comment: @WannyMiarelli is correct. It will return the filtered subarrays and not the full object with the filtered surnames. Also the code above has errors (string check instead of integer and typo surName).

Comment: this solution is not producing expected output : https://jsbin.com/dunuqeyeje/edit?js,console

Comment: @LokeshSanapalli, in your final call to `filter` you need to change `surName` to `surname`. Then it works. That was my mistake above. Corrected now.

Comment: Hi @AndrewEisenberg! Thanks for your input. Now after 4 years I've decided to change the accepted answer to one that is using spread operator since it seems to be better suited for 2020 :) Thanks, and no hard feelings, I hope :)

Comment: This answer still has problems and should be edited. In the last filter change  the '1' to 1

Answer (score 24):

```
let filteredArray = arrayOfElements
  .filter((element) => 
    element.subElements.some((subElement) => subElement.surname == 1))
  .map(element => {
    return Object.assign({}, element, {subElements : element.subElements.filter(subElement => subElement.surname == 1)});

  });
```

Comment: this will give the expected response when you'll merge the filtered array with parent object "subElement".

Comment: this returned the expected response

Comment: This worked for me, same context and I got the exact response

Comment: This worked for me as well

Answer (score 8):

Just improved the answers above

```js
let elements = 
    [
        {
           "name": "a",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {"surname": 1},
             {"surname": 2}
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "b",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {"surname": 3},
             {"surname": 1}
           ]
        },
        {
           "name": "c",
           "subElements": 
           [
             {"surname": 2},
             {"surname": 5}
           ]
        }
    ];
var value = 1;

var filteredArray = elements
.filter(element => element.subElements
  .some(subElement => subElement.surname === value)
)
.map(element => {
  let n = Object.assign({}, element, {'subElements': element.subElements.filter(
    subElement => subElement.surname === value
  )})
  return n;
})

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this solution:

```
data_filter = arrayOfElements.filter(function (element) {
    return element.subElements.some( function (subElement) {
        return subElement.surname === surname
    });
});
```

Comment: it will not return exact expected response, but return all the surnames within an object found

Answer (score 1):

You can make it generic as well:

#### Logic

- Find all distinct surnames and loop over them
- Filter every object to check if surnames exists. If yes, copy object using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and set `subElements` value to filtered list.
- Create a temp array to hold all similar objects and push copied object to it.
- Push this array to final array on every iteration of distinct surname.

#### Sample

```js
let arrayOfElements=[{name:"a",subElements:[{surname:1},{surname:2}]},{name:"b",subElements:[{surname:3},{surname:1}]},{name:"c",subElements:[{surname:2},{surname:5}]}];
 let distinct_surnames = [];
 arrayOfElements.forEach(function(el) {
   el.subElements.forEach(function(s) {
     if (distinct_surnames.indexOf(s.surname) < 0) distinct_surnames.push(s.surname)
   });
 })

 let result = [];
 distinct_surnames.forEach(function(sn) {
   let inter = [];
   arrayOfElements.forEach(function(el) {
     let f = el.subElements.filter(function(sub) {
       return sub.surname === sn;
     });
     if (f.length > 0) {
       let _tmp = Object.assign({}, el);
       _tmp.subElements = f;
       inter.push(_tmp);
     }
   });
   result.push(inter);
 })
 console.log(result)
```

**Note:** Arrow functions are used to keep the reference of `this`. If you are not using `this` inside function, you can use normal functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function display_message() {
  let arrayOfElements = [{
    "name": "a",
    "subElements": [{
      "surname": 1
    }, {
      "surname": 2
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "b",
    "subElements": [{
      "surname": 3
    }, {
      "surname": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "c",
    "subElements": [{
      "surname": 2
    }, {
      "surname": 5
    }]
  }];
  // console.log(arrayOfElements);
var surname = 1;
  let filteredArray = arrayOfElements.filter((element) => element.subElements.some((subElement) => subElement.surname === surname));

  for(var data in filteredArray){
    filteredArray[data].subElements = {"surname": surname};
    }
  console.log(filteredArray);

}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="display_message();" value="click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredArray = arrayOfElements
    .filter((element) => 
        element.subElements.some((subElement) => subElement.surname === 1))
    .map(element => {
        let newElt = Object.assign({}, element); // copies element
        newElt.subElements = newElt.subElements.filter(subElement => subElement.surName === '1'); 
        return newElt;
    });
```

is more correctly

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dataSource = [
  {
    groupName: 'FORD',
    optionItem: [
      {
        label: 'Fiesta',
        data: 'Fiesta',
      },
      {
        label: 'Fusion',
        data: 'Fusion',
      },
      {
        label: 'Mustang',
        data: 'Mustang',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    groupName: 'HONDA',
    optionItem: [
      {
        label: 'Accord',
        data: 'Accord',
      },
      {
        label: 'Civic',
        data: 'Civic',
      },
      {
        label: 'CR-V',
        data: 'CR-V',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    groupName: 'HYUNDAI',
    optionItem: [
      {
        label: 'Accent',
        data: 'Accent',
      },
      {
        label: 'Sonata',
        data: 'Sonata',
      },
      {
        label: 'Tucson',
        data: 'Tucson',
      },
    ],
  },
];

let filterValue = dataSource.filter(a => {
  a.optionItem = a.optionItem.filter(
    option => option.data.toLowerCase().indexOf('Fiesta'.toLowerCase()) !== -1
  );
  return a.optionItem.length;
});

console.log('filter value ', filterValue);


/**
OUTPUT
=========================================
filter value =>  [{
  "groupName": "FORD",
  "optionItem": [
    {
      "label": "Fiesta",
      "data": "Fiesta"
    }
  ]
}] 
**/
```