# Get value checkbox inside table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation here where I have a table with multiple column and a checkbox for one of the column.

Table structure

[image: Table structure]

I've tried to put some formControlName in the checkbox in the table. but the console prompt an error that `no value accessor for form control`

```
<nz-table #filterTable [nzLoading]="loading" nzTitle="Assign a new role to the group" nzBordered>
      <thead nzSingleSort>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th nzShowSort nzSortKey="module">Module</th>
            <th></th>
            <th nzShowFilter [nzFilters]="filterrole" (nzFilterChange)="updateFilter($event)">Role</th>
            <th style="min-width: 120px;">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let module of listofmodules">
          <tr *ngFor="let role of module.role">
            <td>{{module.module}}</td>
            <td nzShowCheckbox [(nzChecked)]="role.checked" (nzCheckedChange)="refreshStatus(module.id, role)" name='tableCheck'
              id='tableCheck'>
            </td>
            <td>{{role}}</td>
            <td><a>View</a></td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
```

There is a button to submit the value to the back end. in the submit button (click) function, I am using the `const formObj = this.validateForm.getRawValue();` and using the `JSON.stringify` to turn it into JSON format.

I am expecting to get the value of the checkbox in the table. How do I achieve this ?

EXPECTED RESULT

```
{"moduleid": "testing group 1", "roleheck":"Supervisor"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `(nzCheckedChange)="refreshStatus(module.id, role)"`. Just filter your data by checking `role.checked` on Submit and pass filtered data to backend. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value)

Comment: hi @Parshwa Shah, thank you for the reply. Can you teach me how to filter my data by checking the `role.checked` ? I am kinda new to this angular and typescript.

Comment: Check reference link

Comment: the link you gave is not related to checkbox. its the question regarding array. kindly advice.

Comment: That you will need to filter checked role.