# Filter pipe for multiple fields on different levels (nested array)

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, pipe

I'm trying to filter a jobs list by Job Type, Job Tags (nested array) and job payement.
I have a list of checkboxes that contain job types and job tags and two inputs that contain minimum payement and maximum payement

For now, i can only filter the job type with multiple checkboxes value, but i couldn't filter the job tags, neither the payement

I tried this solution here :
[Filtering array of objects with arrays based on nested value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value)

It didn't work

My job object :

```
{
    "jobTitle" :"Whatever",
    "jobDescription" : "",
    "jobType" : "EXTRA", // Job Type can be either EXTRA or FULL
    "jobPayement" : 5,   
    "tags" : ["RESTAURANT","EVENT"], //Job Tags are defined with 4 categories RESTAURANT / EVENT / COFFEE / HOTEL
    "xpOnly" : true,
    "image" : "kitchen.png",
   }
```

My Filter Items (Checkboxes) :

```
this.filterItems = [
      {
        value: 'Coffee',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        value: 'Event',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        value: 'Hotel',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        value: 'Restaurant',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        value: 'FULL',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        value: 'EXTRA',
        checked: false
      },
    ];
```

Filter Conditions and ng for

```
 <a *ngFor="let job of jobs  | fresh: { jobType: ''} : checked();let i = index">
```

My Filter Pipe :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'fresh'
})
export class FreshPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(items: any, filter: any, filterItems: Array<any>, isAnd: boolean): any {
    console.log('Filtering ..');
    if (filter && Array.isArray(items) && filterItems) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);
      let checkedItems = filterItems.filter(item => { return item.checked; });
      if (!checkedItems || checkedItems.length === 0) { return items; }
      if (isAnd) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((acc1, keyName) =>
                (acc1 && checkedItems.reduce((acc2, checkedItem) => acc2 && new RegExp(item[keyName], 'gi').test(checkedItem.value) || checkedItem.value === "", true))
              , true)
              );
      } else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return checkedItems.some((checkedItem) => {
              return new RegExp(item[keyName], 'gi').test(checkedItem.value) || checkedItem.value === "";
            });
          });
        });
      } 
    } else {
      return items;
    }
  }


}

checked() {
    return this.filterItems.filter(item => { return item.checked; });
  }
```

Like i said, for now i got only the filter on Job Type,It would be great if we can find a solution to filter the tags and payement. I'm available for any extra informations
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Worth a read: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe So first, I would recommend to do the logic in your component ts.

Comment: It's the first time i use Pipe, i just followed a tutorial. I'll give it a read to understand the logic. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general is a bad idea use a pipe to filter options. see the posibility of has two variables, "jobs" and "filteredJobs".

for filter by filterItems, it's only create an array with the tags and use "some".

```
    //create the array with the tags, e.g. ["Event","Restaurant"]
    const filter=this.filterItems.filter(x=>x.checked).map(x=>x.value);

    //use "some"
    this.filteredJobs=this.jobs.filter(job=>
        job.tags.some(t=>filter.indexOf(t)>=0)
    )
```