# How to Return Values from filter of filter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to get all student who has Maths as subject

```js
var student = [{
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 15,
  subject: ['Maths', 'Science'],
}, {
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 15,
  subject: ['Hindi', 'Science'],
}, {
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 15,
  subject: ['Maths', 'English'],
}];
```

I Have tried this but doesn't work:

```js
student.filter(x=>x.subject.filter(y=>y=='Maths'));
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine `filter()` width `some()` to check if there is a subject `Maths`

```js
var student = [{
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Maths', 'Science'],
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Hindi', 'Science'],
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Maths', 'English'],
  }
];

console.log(student.filter(x => x.subject.some(y => y == 'Maths')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
student.filter(x=>x.subject.indexOf('Maths')!=-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
student.filter(x => x.subject.some(y => y == 'Maths')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply use `includes` inside `filter`.

```js
 var student=[
    {
      name:'XYZ',
      age:15,
      subject:['Maths','Science'],
    },
    {
      name:'XYZ',
      age:15,
      subject:['Hindi','Science'],
    },
    {
      name:'XYZ',
      age:15,
      subject:['Maths','English'],
    }
   ]
 student=student.filter(x=>x['subject'].includes('Maths'));
 console.log(student);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. To search for the first occurrence in an array, use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function.

This will return the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

So we need to check the result is **> -1** to indicate we have a match.

See the snippet:

```js
var student = [{
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Maths', 'Science']
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Hindi', 'Science']
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Maths', 'English']
  }
];

console.log(student.filter(x => x.subject.indexOf('Maths') > -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use includes() method in typescript

```js
var student = [{
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Maths', 'Science'],
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Hindi', 'Science'],
  },
  {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 15,
    subject: ['Maths', 'English'],
  }
];

console.log(student.filter(x => x.subject.includes('Maths')));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in more detail:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38375768/7562674

As per your scenario:-

```
  var st=student.filter((stud) => 
  stud.subject.some((subElement) => subElement === "Maths")
 );
  console.log(st)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried looking for it I didn't get that time so I asked

Answer (score 1):

```js
var student = [{
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 15,
  subject: ['Maths', 'Science'],
}, {
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 15,
  subject: ['Hindi', 'Science'],
}, {
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 15,
  subject: ['Maths', 'English'],
}];

let findResult = (subject) => student.filter(o => o.subject.find( i => i == subject ));
let result = findResult('Maths');
console.log(result);
```

> You can use `filter method` and `find method` which returns the value
>   of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided
>   testing function.