# Filtering array of objects with arrays based on nested value to extract specific fields

Tags: javascript, filter

Something related to the same question as [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value/62563793#62563793)..

```js
var mainArray = [{ "name":"George", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 1, "age": 11},{"id": 2, "age": 22}]}, 
                { "name":"George", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 2, "age": 34}]}, 
                { "name":"Raghu", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 3, "age": 45}]}, 
                { "name":"Sudhir", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 4, "age": 23}]}];
var filteredGeorge = mainArray.filter(element => element.name === "George")
var final = filteredGeorge.map(element => ({"name": element.name, "id": element.nest.filter(element => element.age == 22)}))
console.log(final)
```

What I am interested in output is actually something like:

```js
  {
    "name": "George",
    "id": 2      
    ]
  }
```

It need not even be an array, else it can even be just an array of this object.

I am mainly looking for the name and id value or say there was one more key called say dept after name, then dept and id is what I want finally where name is George and age is 22.

Comment: What if there are multiple items with same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the description of expected output, I'm guessing you're looking for a single matching record based on multiple criteria match.

If so, you may check whether [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) source array record fulfills both of desired criteria and assign desired properties (`name` and `id`) of the output object accordingly:

```js
const src = [{"name":"George","nest":[{"id":1,"age":11},{"id":2,"age":22}]},{"name":"George","nest":[{"id":2,"age":34}]},{"name":"Raghu","nest":[{"id":3,"age":45}]},{"name":"Sudhir","nest":[{"id":4,"age":23}]}],
                  
      getItemByNameAndAge = (arr, _name,_age) => {
        let name = null, id = null
        src.some(o => 
          o.name == _name && 
          o.nest.some(n => 
            n.age == _age ?
            (id = n.id, name = _name, true) :
            false
          )
        )
        return {name,id}
      }
      
console.log(getItemByNameAndAge(src,'George', 22))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Out of all answers, I like this the best. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying a function to array's map method that also checks the nested array for the age using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Since the functions returns undefined for not matching entries, it needs to get rid of these afterwards. Here it is done using `.find(Boolean)`

This is not a beauty but I hope it helps you:

```js
var mainArray = [{
        'name': 'George',
        'nest': [{ 'id': 1, 'age': 11 }, { 'id': 2, 'age': 22 }],
    },
    {
        'name': 'George',
        'nest': [{ 'id': 2, 'age': 34 }],
    },
    {
        'name': 'Raghu',
        'nest': [{ 'id': 3, 'age': 45 }],
    },
    {
        'name': 'Sudhir',
        'nest': [{ 'id': 4, 'age': 23 }],
    }];

var george22 = mainArray.map((entry) => {
    if (entry.name !== 'George')
        return;
    var nested = entry.nest.find((nested) => nested.age === 22);
    if (!nested)
        return;
    return { name: entry.name, id: nested.id };
}).find(Boolean);

console.log(george22);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another approach using map

```js
var mainArray = [{ "name":"George", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 1, "age": 11},{"id": 2, "age": 22}]}, 
                { "name":"George", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 2, "age": 34}]}, 
                { "name":"Raghu", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 3, "age": 45}]}, 
                { "name":"Sudhir", 
                  "nest": [{"id": 4, "age": 23}]}]

res=mainArray.map(({...rest})=>({...rest,"nest":rest.nest.length>1?rest.nest[rest.nest.length-1].id:rest.nest[0].id}))
console.log(res)
```