# Filter Javascript objects by values in a nested object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has another objects inside, and I need to filter the objects by a value inside the second object.

```
userone:{
  name:"user1"
  lastname:"uzer1"
  task:{
     attendance: "1"
     taskname: "whatever"
  }
}
usertwo:{
  name:"user2"
  lastname:"uzer2"
  task:{
     attendance: "0"
     taskname: "whatever2"
  }
}
```

I want to get all the users whose attendance is `1`. I have gone only as far as filtering by `name` and `lastname`, which I can do like this `Object.values(userslist).filter(e => e.firstname == 'user1');` But not sure how to get inside the second object and filter by that value.

Also, the `task` object does not exist in all the objects.

Comment: `e.task.attendance == 1`

Comment: Firstly `firstname` isn't in the object. But unless i'm missing something, you just need `e.task.taskname`

Comment: `Object.values(userslist).filter(e => e.task.attendace == '1');`

Comment: Perhaps you would be better going by using `[{},{}]` or `{456:{}, 36:{}}` (user IDs) rather than `{userone:{}, usertwo:{}}` ... But yeah. `e` is your *user*. And PS, you're missing *comma*s all over the place.

Comment: I get an error saying `cannot read property attendance of undefined`. Some of the objects do not have a `task` object inside them. How can I account for that?

Comment: See this page : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value"