# How to filter array based on nested value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which I'm trying to filter based on a certain nested value, without getting any other elements.

```
const arrayData = [ 
{ 
    country: "Country X", 
    games: [ 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game1', 
            players: [{ name: 'John', status:'Active' },{ name: 'Rob', status:'Suspended' }] 
        }, 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game2', 
            players: [{ name: 'Saly', status:'Blocked' }] 
        }, 
    ] 
}, 
{ 
    country: "Country Y", 
    games: [ 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game1', 
            players: [{ name: 'Sindy', status:'Pending' },{ name: 'someone', status:'Rejected' }] 
        }, 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game2', 
            players: [{ name: 'Alex', status:'New' },{ name: 'Nic', status:'Old' }] 
        }, 
    ] 
}, 
];
```

What I have tried:

```
let output = arrayData.filter(eachVal => { 
let opt = eachVal.games.some(( 
    { players }) => players 
    .some(({ status}) => status === 'Active')); 
return opt; 
})
```

Expected result for finding **all players** with value **status** : **'Active'**:

```
{ 
country: "Country X", 
games: [ 
    { 
        gameTitle: 'Game1', 
        players: [{ name: 'John', status:'Active' }] 
    }
] 
}
```

But the result:

```
[{"country":"Country X","games":[{"gameTitle":"Game1","players":[{"name":"John","status":"Active"},{"name":"Rob","status":"Suspended"}]},{"gameTitle":"Game2","players":[{"name":"Saly","status":"Blocked"}]}]}]
```

Comment: um, if you want the players with active status, why do you want the country and the games array?

Comment: @TheBombSquad Because I need to display their values as well!

Comment: @Sam this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value/38375768

Comment: I've seen it before, but the filter applied there for the first level only, and I couldn't do it inside the players list. @OzgurSar

Comment: just solved.. nested filter logic i used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy. You just need some `map` and `filter`:

```js
const arrayData = [ 
{ 
    country: "Country X", 
    games: [ 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game1', 
            players: [{ name: 'John', status:'Active' },{ name: 'Rob', status:'Suspended' }] 
        }, 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game2', 
            players: [{ name: 'Saly', status:'Blocked' }] 
        }, 
    ] 
}, 
{ 
    country: "Country Y", 
    games: [ 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game1', 
            players: [{ name: 'Sindy', status:'Pending' },{ name: 'someone', status:'Rejected' }] 
        }, 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game2', 
            players: [{ name: 'Alex', status:'New' },{ name: 'Nic', status:'Old' }] 
        }, 
    ] 
}, 
];

/*------------------------------- This is the answer -------------------------------*/
let result = arrayData.map(a => ({...a, games: a.games.map(g => ({...g, players: g.players.filter(p => p.status === 'Active')})).filter(g => g.players.length)})).filter(a => a.games.length)
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
arrayData.map(({country, games: g}) => {
  
  const games = g.map((g) => { 
    const players = g.players.filter((p) => p.status === 'Active')
  
    return {...g, players}
  })
  .filter(({players}) => players.length > 0)
  
  return {country, games}
}).filter(({games}) => games.length>0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic is nested filter through each level and assigning the finds back to their respective places and using `forEach` logic to see if an object has an "Active" value

```js
const arrayData = [ 
{ 
    country: "Country X", 
    games: [ 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game1', 
            players: [{ name: 'John', status:'Active' },{ name: 'Rob', status:'Suspended' }] 
        }, 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game2', 
            players: [{ name: 'Saly', status:'Blocked' }] 
        }, 
    ] 
}, 
{ 
    country: "Country Y", 
    games: [ 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game1', 
            players: [{ name: 'Sindy', status:'Pending' },{ name: 'someone', status:'Rejected' }] 
        }, 
        { 
            gameTitle: 'Game2', 
            players: [{ name: 'Alex', status:'New' },{ name: 'Nic', status:'Old' }] 
        }, 
    ] 
}, 
];

//answer
let arr=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayData))
arr=arr.filter(a=>{
  let f=a.games; let i=false
  f=f.filter(b=>{
    let x=b.players; let j=false
    x=x.filter(c=>c.status=="Active")
    x.forEach(c=>{if(c.status=="Active"){j=true}})
    b.players=x; return j
  })
  f.forEach(b=>{
    b.players.forEach(c=>{if(c.status=="Active"){i=true}})
  })
  a.games=f; return i
})
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd "recursively" select the valid elements at each level and map on each filtered array to build the correct output:

```js
const selectActivePlayers = (players) => players.filter(player => player.status === "Active");
const selectValidGames = (games) => games.filter(game => selectActivePlayers(game.players).length > 0)
const selectValidCountries = (countries) => countries.filter(country => selectValidGames(country.games).length > 0);


const cleanCountries = selectValidCountries(arrayData).map(country => ({
  ...country,
  games: selectValidGames(country.games).map(game => ({
    ...game,
    players: selectActivePlayers(game.players)
  }))
}))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "country": "Country X",
    "games": [
      {
        "gameTitle": "Game1",
        "players": [
          {
            "name": "John",
            "status": "Active"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```