# Filtering nested objects via Attribute with Javascript-

Tags: javascript

I have an array of nested objects, I want to filter this to return only the object tjat contains an author who's age === 21.

I've attempted to implement this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375646/filtering-array-of-objects-with-arrays-based-on-nested-value), but I keep having 'x is not a function' returned.

```
let arrayOfElements = 
[
  {
  author: { name: 'Kim', age: 21 },
  employment: { employer: 'Logiothech', role: 'Human Resources' }
  }
  
  {
  author: { name: 'John', age: 62 },
  employment: { employer: 'Logiothech', role: 'Human Resources' }
  }
  
  {
  author: { name: 'Mary', age: 31 },
  employment: { employer: 'Logiothech', role: 'Human Resources' }
  }
  
];
```

What I have tried: (I believe I'm incorrectly using subElements, but unsure what to correctly sub in it's place)

```
 let filteredMap =  array_of_elements.map((element) => {
return {...element, subElements: element.subElements.filter((subElement) => subElement.author.age === 21)}
})
```

Comment: You want to filter at the top level, not map. `let filteredMap =  array_of_elements.filter(element => element.author.age === 21);`

Comment: In your case, there is no prop named `subElements`. You may use a simple `.find` (or `.filter`, if you expect to have more than one matched results) to achieve your objective. Something like so: `arrayOfElements.find(x => x?.author?.age === 21);`. Here, `x` is just a placeholder - it symbolizes the current element being iterated from within the array. So, `x` has props same as the elements of the array.

Comment: also see: [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You just need the .filter array method. the .map method is when you want to make a change to each element in the array. Here is what I came up with:

```
let filteredArray = arrayOfElements.filter((element) => element.author.age == 21)
```

Full code:

```js
let arrayOfElements = 
[
  {
  author: { name: 'Kim', age: 21 },
  employment: { employer: 'Logiothech', role: 'Human Resources' }
  },
  
  {
  author: { name: 'John', age: 62 },
  employment: { employer: 'Logiothech', role: 'Human Resources' }
  },
  
  {
  author: { name: 'Mary', age: 31 },
  employment: { employer: 'Logiothech', role: 'Human Resources' }
  }
  
];

let filteredArray = arrayOfElements.filter((element) => element.author.age == 21)

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate and should be flagged for closure instead of answering. (also your answer is covered in my comment above ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you're overthinking it a bit. Try this:

```
arrayOfElements.filter(element => element.author.age === 21);
```

This will return an array of objects (in this case one) that have an author whose age is 21.