How do I filter this array of deep nested object in Typescript/Angular?
tableData is an array of PDO objects. Each PDO can have 0 or more advocacy (pdo_advocacies). Each advocacy can have 0 or more programs (pdo_programs). Like this:


//array of PDO object
[
    {
        id: 1,
        pdo_currency: "PHP",
        name: "Gemango",
        abbreviation: "Gemango",
        dt_founded: "May. 02, 2024",
        dt_created_at: "Jan. 01, 1970",
    //array of PDO advocacies
        pdo_advocacies: [
            {
                id: 1,
                advocacy: "PDO Operations",
                pdo_id: 1,
        //array of PDO programs
                pdo_programs: [
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        program: "PDO Budget",
                        pdo_advocacy_id: 1,
                        pdo_id: 1,
                        admin_beneficiary_category_id: 2,
                        beneficiary_category: {
                            id: 2,
                            name: "elders",
                        },
                        program_priority: {
                            id: 295,
                            name: "High",
                        },
                        program_category: null,
                        proposed_date: null,
                        funding_needs: "20000.00",
                        admin_beneficiary_category: {
                            id: 2,
                            category: "Children",
                        },
                        pdo_program_locations: [
                            {
                                id: 6,
                                pdo_program_id: 6,
                                location: {
                                    id: 3,
                                    name: "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES",
                                },
                                funding_needs_location: "0.00",
                                unit_of_item: null,
                                num_of_items: 0,
                                num_of_beneficiaries: 0,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                advocacy: "Unrestricted",
                pdo_id: 1,
                pdo_programs: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        program: "Unrestricted Funds",
                        pdo_advocacy_id: 2,
                        pdo_id: 1,
                        admin_beneficiary_category_id: null,
                        beneficiary_category: null,
                        program_priority: null,
                        program_category: null,
                        proposed_date: null,
                        funding_needs: "0.00",
                        admin_beneficiary_category: null,
                        pdo_program_locations: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                pdo_program_id: 1,
                                location: {
                                    id: 1,
                                    name: "Main",
                                },
                                funding_needs_location: "0.00",
                                unit_of_item: null,
                                num_of_items: 0,
                                num_of_beneficiaries: 0,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];



selectedOptions


[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Children"
    }
]



This should have filtered and return only the pdo, advocacy and programs that has an admin_beneficiary_category.category of "Children".
Filter Implementation


        this.filteredTableData = this.tableData.filter((pdo) => {
          return pdo.pdo_advocacies.some((advocacy) => {
            return advocacy.pdo_programs.some((program) => {
              return selectedOptions.some((option) => {
                // Check if admin_beneficiary_category is null or undefined
                if (program.admin_beneficiary_category === null || program.admin_beneficiary_category === undefined) {
                  // Check if the option name is 'null'
                  return option.name === 'null';
                }
                // Compare the program category name with the selected option name
                return option.name === program.admin_beneficiary_category.category;
              });              
            });
          });
        });



Actual Output


[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "pdo_currency": "PHP",
        "name": "Gemango",
        "abbreviation": "Gemango",
        "dt_founded": "May. 03, 2024",
        "dt_created_at": "Jan. 01, 1970",
        "pdo_advocacies": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "advocacy": "PDO Operations",
                "pdo_id": 1,
                "pdo_programs": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "program": "PDO Budget",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 1,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 2,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "elders"
                        },
                        "program_priority": {
                            "id": 295,
                            "name": "High"
                        },
                        "program_category": null,
                        "proposed_date": null,
                        "funding_needs": "20000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "category": "Children"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 6,
                                "pdo_program_id": 6,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "advocacy": "Unrestricted",
                "pdo_id": 1,
                "pdo_programs": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "program": "Unrestricted Funds",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 2,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": null,
                        "beneficiary_category": null,
                        "program_priority": null,
                        "program_category": null,
                        "proposed_date": null,
                        "funding_needs": "0.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": null,
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "pdo_program_id": 1,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "name": "Main"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "advocacy": "Scholarship",
                "pdo_id": 1,
                "pdo_programs": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "program": "Scholarship Program for the Carm.O.L. Sisters",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 3,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 4,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "elders"
                        },
                        "program_priority": null,
                        "program_category": null,
                        "proposed_date": null,
                        "funding_needs": "50000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "category": "Elderly"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "pdo_program_id": 2,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "advocacy": "Pastoral Care",
                "pdo_id": 1,
                "pdo_programs": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "program": "Program 1",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 10,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 2,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "elders"
                        },
                        "program_priority": {
                            "id": 295,
                            "name": "High"
                        },
                        "program_category": {
                            "id": 276,
                            "name": "Grant"
                        },
                        "proposed_date": "2024-04-01 16:00:00",
                        "funding_needs": "100000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "category": "Children"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "pdo_program_id": 7,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "50000.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 10,
                                "pdo_program_id": 7,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "50000.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "program": "Test",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 10,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 3,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "children"
                        },
                        "program_priority": null,
                        "program_category": {
                            "id": 276,
                            "name": "Grant"
                        },
                        "proposed_date": null,
                        "funding_needs": "1000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "category": "Community"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 17,
                                "pdo_program_id": 13,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "program": "Test Program",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 10,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 3,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "children"
                        },
                        "program_priority": {
                            "id": 297,
                            "name": "Low"
                        },
                        "program_category": {
                            "id": 276,
                            "name": "Grant"
                        },
                        "proposed_date": "2024-04-01 16:00:00",
                        "funding_needs": "100000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "category": "Community"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 18,
                                "pdo_program_id": 14,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 19,
                                "pdo_program_id": 14,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "program": "Hello World",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 10,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": null,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "children"
                        },
                        "program_priority": {
                            "id": 297,
                            "name": "Low"
                        },
                        "program_category": null,
                        "proposed_date": "2024-04-07 16:00:00",
                        "funding_needs": "1000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": null,
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 20,
                                "pdo_program_id": 15,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]



Expected Output:


[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "pdo_currency": "PHP",
        "name": "Gemango",
        "abbreviation": "Gemango",
        "dt_founded": "May. 03, 2024",
        "dt_created_at": "Jan. 01, 1970",
        "pdo_advocacies": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "advocacy": "PDO Operations",
                "pdo_id": 1,
                "pdo_programs": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "program": "PDO Budget",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 1,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 2,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "elders"
                        },
                        "program_priority": {
                            "id": 295,
                            "name": "High"
                        },
                        "program_category": null,
                        "proposed_date": null,
                        "funding_needs": "20000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "category": "Children"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 6,
                                "pdo_program_id": 6,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "0.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "advocacy": "Pastoral Care",
                "pdo_id": 1,
                "pdo_programs": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "program": "Program 1",
                        "pdo_advocacy_id": 10,
                        "pdo_id": 1,
                        "admin_beneficiary_category_id": 2,
                        "beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "elders"
                        },
                        "program_priority": {
                            "id": 295,
                            "name": "High"
                        },
                        "program_category": {
                            "id": 276,
                            "name": "Grant"
                        },
                        "proposed_date": "2024-04-01 16:00:00",
                        "funding_needs": "100000.00",
                        "admin_beneficiary_category": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "category": "Children"
                        },
                        "pdo_program_locations": [
                            {
                                "id": 7,
                                "pdo_program_id": 7,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "50000.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 10,
                                "pdo_program_id": 7,
                                "location": {
                                    "id": 3,
                                    "name": "CEBU CITY, CEBU, PHILIPPINES"
                                },
                                "funding_needs_location": "50000.00",
                                "unit_of_item": null,
                                "num_of_items": 0,
                                "num_of_beneficiaries": 0
                            }
                        ]
                    }        
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]



Complete Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-azu5d2?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Please include all relevant code (and only the relevant code) as text, preferably a Stack Snippet, in your question here

Hi @mykaf, I've updated my post and provided all relevant code except tableData as I'm limited to 3000 characters in stackoverflow. Nevertheless, the complete code can be found on https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-azu5d2?file=src%2Fmain.ts

" see tableData in (link) as stack-overflow limits body content to 3000 characters.": sorry, but this is not what you should do. Please reduce the problem to the smallest possible data and code to reproduce the problem. Reduce the data set to only few rows, and remove all object properties that are irrelevant.

Hi @trincot, you're right. My bad, I've truncated my tableData and provided a brief explanation of the object structure.

I finally get it with tips from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53115809/12438210 post.
Basically, I need to use a combination of nested map and spread operator instead of nested some and filter only the deepest level object.


        this.filteredTableData = this.tableData
          .map(pdo => {
            // Filter pdo_advocacies
            const filteredAdvocacies = pdo.pdo_advocacies
              .map(advocacy => {
                // Filter pdo_programs for each advocacy
                const filteredPrograms = advocacy.pdo_programs.filter(program => {
                  return selectedOptions.some(option => {
                    if (!program.admin_beneficiary_category) {
                      return option.name === 'null';
                    }
                    return option.name === program.admin_beneficiary_category.category;
                  });
                });
                // Return advocacy only if it has filtered programs
                return {
                  ...advocacy,
                  pdo_programs: filteredPrograms,
                };
              })
              .filter(advocacy => advocacy.pdo_programs.length > 0); // Filter out advocacies with no programs

            // Return pdo only if it has filtered advocacies
            return {
              ...pdo,
              pdo_advocacies: filteredAdvocacies,
            };
          })
          .filter(pdo => pdo.pdo_advocacies.length > 0); // Filter out pdo with no advocacies



